# Spring MVC 3: Find out locale within a filter

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, filter, locale, interceptor

**Environment:**
In my Spring MVC 3.0.5 application I try to add caching, html compression and some other things using a filter as described here: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/filters.html?page=3

**Problem:**
This works, but unfortunately I cannot figure out the current Spring MVC Locale, because the filter kicks in before Spring MVC with its CookieLocaleResolver, LocaleChangeInterceptor etc is started.

**Solution?:**
Is there a workaround to get the locale or does anybody know a good Spring build-in alternative to filters (eg an interceptor which starts before the request goes to any controller and ends after the view in form of a JSPs is processed)

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of spring alternatives like already build in Filters to set the http caching headers (if this is what you are looking for). (For example AbstractCachingViewResolver, or [WebContentInterceptor](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.4/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/WebContentInterceptor.html))

Anyway: Spring provides the [HandlerInterceptor Interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). Which is the kind of intercepter you asked for. They are just defined inside the `<mvc:interceptors>` tag.

@See [Spring Reference: Chapter 15.4.1 Intercepting requests - the HandlerInterceptor interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

And see also some Stack Overflow question about the Interceptors.

And this [Blog: Spring MVC 3.0 annotations and HTTP/1.1 Cache-Control headers](http://www.i-develop.be/blog/2010/07/30/spring-mvc-3-0-http-cache-control-headers/) for an example how a interceptor (web content interceptor) is configured.

Comment: When digging deeper into interceptors, I could not find even one example how to use HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion(), which seems like what I was looking for. Can anybody advise how to extract the generated html body from the given response object?